Problem with load more button. Always getting stale element. How to deal with it?
I have a simple program that get to result's page, click product by product and scrape the information on product's page. There is one site that has the load more button. So the approach I'm trying to do is: click on the load more button while is still visible, if not
def extract_prodirectsports_data():
    print("entered")
    print(url_line)
    url_line = "https://www.prodirectsport.com/soccer/l/adults/departments-boots/activity-football/brand-adidas/silo-predator/"
    spreadsheet_data = []
    pdf_data = []
    sizes = []

    cotacao_libra()  # Assuming this function is already defined
    i = 0
    driver.get(url_line)
    
    # Cookies
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@title='Accept all cookies']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='zonos']")))
    close_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class = 'z-close']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close_button)
    
    close_button_2 = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label='Close']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", close_button_2)
    
    # Initialize DataFrame for the spreadsheet
    df_spreadsheet = pd.DataFrame(columns=SPREADSHEET_COLUMNS)
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
    
    x = 0
    driver.maximize_window()

    view_more_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'product-listing__view-more']/button")
    while True:
        """view_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'product-listing__view-more']/button")))"""
        
        if view_more_button is not None:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", view_more_button)
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", view_more_button)
            x += 1
            print(x)
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            pass

    products_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'product-listing__grid']"))
    )
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", products_list)
        
    for index, value in enumerate(products_list):
        products_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'product-listing__grid']//div[@class = '_root_129ai_6 product-listing__grid-item']/a")))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", products_list[index])
        driver.save_screenshot("window.png")
        image_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "img")))
        image = image_element.get_attribute("src")
        i += 1
        print(i)
        actions.move_to_element(products_list[index]).perform()
                
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", products_list[index])

the problem is: it clicks on the load more button until it doesn't appear no more... but it returns me staleelement exception
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element with the reference e5fa4a38-375f-488b-b118-2b240e35fcf7 is stale; either its node document is not the active document, or it is no longer connected to the DOM; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#stale-element-reference-exception
trying to find a right approach to deal with load more button and stale element exception.

When you click the button, that changes the page contents, so the original button element doesn't exist anymore.  Inside the loop you need to find the new button element.

That's not the problem. @JohnGordon. The problem is that it has to go stale. It will click until the element doesn't exist anymore, when the element is stale, the program continues.

I'm not sure you understood what I meant.  When you click the button, the page is dynamically updated and a new button is created.  But view_more_button is still the original button element, which no longer exists.

Please try to move locating element inside the while loop.
Do not forget to add break to while loop. Currently it is infinite loop.
If you still get that try to add try and catch and find the iteration where the exception starts
